# How do I change the color of the deleted text on the left side of a vimdiff?

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, highlight, vimdiff

My colors currently look like this, with the text highlighted green on both sides:
[image: My setup]

I would like it to be red on the left, and green on the right.

I tried to change the DiffDelete highlight, but that is for the greyed out area opposite the green highlighted text. And when I change the DiffAdd highlight, both sides change! I know that this is possible, this setup pulls it off:
[image: Some other guy's setup]

I believe the theme used there is Tokyo Night, but [this isn't accomplished in the theme](https://github.com/folke/tokyonight.nvim/blob/main/lua/tokyonight/colors.lua#L116-L121), when I tried it, it had the same behavior- green on both sides. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of [diffview.nvim](https://github.com/sindrets/diffview.nvim/blob/9f00ed07c16662bd4280ecc4bfe7d35a65b1f6b7/doc/diffview.txt#LL359C2-L359C2). `:help diffview-config-enhanced_diff_hl`

To set the colors after enabling this option, `DiffAdd` remains the same, the text on the left side is set at `DiffviewDiffAddAsDelete`, and the dashes opposite the DiffAdd blocks are set at `DiffviewDiffDelete`.